# Animated progress meter on scroll going backwards

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm doing the 'ol animate a progress bar on scroll, I've used a great bit of code from [Darren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1678148/darren) and I'm using waypoints, I was hoping sticking the Jquery in between a waypoint was going to work, it kinda does, but goes backwards!

Here's the code:

```
<div class="goals" id="PB">
<div class="wh-align">
    <div class="meter">
        <span style="width: 40%"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

var waypoint = new Waypoint({
element: document.getElementById('PB'),
handler: function() {
$(function() {
$(".meter > span").each(function() {
    $(this)
        .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
        .width(0)
        .animate({
             width: $(this).data("origWidth")
             }, 1200);
});
});
},
offset: '40%'
})
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/n115Lmq0/) - I'm not sure I've uploaded waypoints properly though!

Comment: Can you provide an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  A snippet or fiddle would be great.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply I've just updated it to have one @adamdc78

Comment: The skin of the scroll bar seems to be animated (left to right) but the progress itself doesn't seem to move.

Comment: I think it's because I havent uploaded waypoints properly... @adamdc78